# HibernateFilter.doFilter ServletException?

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat6, servletexception

I have pretty much zero experience setting up servers, but currently my job is to set one up (don't ask why). It's an an apache-tomcat6 server.

I followed some instructions step by step, and when it came time to test that everything was working, here's what I got:

[image: The error!]

I know this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Please let me know if there's any further information I can provide to help!

Comment: I guess that getting errors could be scary at first glance, but when you read the description *java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ...* then you could have an idea what's going on and search a solution to the error. In this case, it looks like you forgot to add a jar (or jars) in your web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing `CertificateAuthInvalidCertException` class in your classpath.
Add it to tomcat / application

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I suppose in retrospect this should have been easier to figure out. Sorry all. Was freaked out.